# How to change the camera in three.js / editor using only scripts?

Tags: three.js, camera

How to change the type of camera used in three.js/editor? I want to do this using scripts, and not using the add camera button (Add → Orthographic Camera). I try to announce the camera again, but I can't. I'm trying to check the view of the main camera using the function (console. log(camera)) — the console shows that the camera has changed. But, when you click the PLAY button, the view remains the same as it was. Thank you for your help and feedback, I am very grateful for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you are looking for since cameras are handled within the editor. You can't use scripts to change the type of camera used for rendering.

In general, there is no full support for orthographic cameras in the editor. For example the editor's controls only support perspective cameras as well as the app player that playbacks exported/published applications. However, there is a feature request at GitHub that tracks the improvement of orthographic camera support:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16008